# R system() function not running curl command properly

Tags: r, curl, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to use the TD Ameritrade API in R to make automated stock trades. To make an order I have a curl command that works perfectly in the command line of my windows 10 computer. However, when I try to run it in R using system() it does not work. This is what works fine and makes the right order in the command line:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer IqxYSgM...long auth token here...bC00B75E" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"orderType\": \"MARKET\",\"session\": \"NORMAL\",\"duration\": \"DAY\",\"orderStrategyType\": \"SINGLE\",\"orderLegCollection\": [{\"instruction\": \"Buy\",\"quantity\": 2,\"instrument\": {\"symbol\": \"GOOG\",\"assetType\": \"EQUITY\"}}]}" "https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/accounts/862xxxxxx/orders"
```

But the exact same thing does not work from R using the system() function:

```
order <- system('curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer IqxYSgM...long auth code here...bC00B75E" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"orderType\": \"MARKET\",\"session\": \"NORMAL\",\"duration\": \"DAY\",\"orderStrategyType\": \"SINGLE\",\"orderLegCollection\": [{\"instruction\": \"Buy\",\"quantity\": 2,\"instrument\": {\"symbol\": \"GOOG\",\"assetType\": \"EQUITY\"}}]}" "https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/accounts/862xxxxxx/orders"')
```

This returns:  "error" : "A validation error occurred while processing the request."

Does anyone know what might be going wrong? I know there are other ways to format this request using RCurl or httr, but I can't quite figure those out either. I am a junior coder.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to reproduce without an Ameritrade authorization, but the fact pattern suggests an encoding problem with the authorization object being passed to system(). Try URLencode (authorization) or URL encode the entire string.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This did not work and I tried many different things but nothing worked. So I ended up using the httr library and massaged the data into the right format using add_headers()  and content_type_json() as arguments and sent the order instructions in the "body" and used POST for the whole thing and  It finally worked!

Comment: great!  what a pain!